# Compare central distribution between two data sets

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, kurtosis

I have a distribution of empirical data (plotted in yellow) that I am comparing to simulated data (plotted in blue).

[image]

I am interested in whether my empirical data (yellow) "clusters" around the midpoint of the plot `0` more than the simulated data (blue).

I have done a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and the results suggest that the data are drawn from different populations (`D = 0.16085`, `p-value = 0.01061`):

```
    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  real$dist and sim$dist
D = 0.16085, p-value = 0.01061
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

As I understand it, the kurtosis reflects the sharpness of the distribution, and, considering my plot is 0-centered, will allow me to estimate this:

```
Empirical kurtosis: 2.388355  
Simulated kurtosis: 1.139189
```

These values indeed suggest that the empirical data form a sharper distribution (are more clustered around 0) than the simulated data.

What I would like to know is:**How can I report this difference between the two populations? Is there a test I can use to compare kurtosis? Is this an appropriate comparison to make?**

---

**Empirical**

```
structure(list(bp = c("5890205", "5890720", "13540579", "243952", 
"244927", "4113213", "4118211", "5318061", "5318184", "16655322", 
"16655452", "178211", "181913", "15234421", "14265613", "17268468", 
"17275492", "19372836", "1333994", "1343586", "1345950", "25253181", 
"25253413", "6153193", "6153589", "24999094", "25000296", "11716582", 
"11717073", "890932", "20522328", "11261335", "11263598", "17655991", 
"17656584", "14059217", "14059362", "284238", "286090", "532735", 
"25231705", "25231949", "817142", "9894889", "11840838", "11861600", 
"12534177", "19941125", "14006279", "14008254", "27563611", "31886737", 
"32060908", "32061196", "32066206", "32068392", "31073815", "31063202", 
"19340213", "19340365", "19828917", "19829841", "8812326", "8815425", 
"18794445", "20261186", "28657288", "31057414", "9014231", "9014231", 
"3057935", "3299323", "3059398", "3145934", "3059398", "3299754", 
"3145934", "3299324", "2791546", "2791749", "3135319", "3139096", 
"3189052", "3273846", "3134262", "3140784", "2796789", "3312289", 
"3060852", "3177592", "3057571", "3277389", "8256961", "8369324", 
"3145469", "3148044", "4574312", "4576608", "3098318", "3125700", 
"3125694", "3126976", "3126976", "3135039", "17286051", "17311472", 
"17286052", "17294628", "17286052", "17311472", "17293196", "17294627", 
"17294628", "17311472", "3160180", "3207188", "3136742", "1129707", 
"1131480", "1130471", "1131480", "12467160", "12577262", "13954981", 
"13983924", "3671509", "3673441", "2988365", "3114256", "3086782", 
"3175561", "3159055", "3266215", "2797173", "3212387", "8854532", 
"8854636", "3002206", "3162171", "3120718", "3194680", "3194680", 
"5451453", "3033491", "3135339", "3157127", "3158876", "3159060", 
"3390022", "3392440", "3393763", "3005992", "3322255", "3005994", 
"3239110", "3005994", "3322257", "17074349", "17132365", "2982503", 
"3192603", "5218491", "5219123", "3139518", "3200151", "3161666", 
"3165214", "3134274", "3140118", "3084862", "3143771", "3135295", 
"3139767", "3138506", "3196544", "3067154", "3159711", "19890758", 
"19892412", "3170682", "3194381", "3195645", "3199669", "3162636", 
"3165496", "2793253", "3266169", "4586393", "4588700", "3169736", 
"3199425", "3199425", "3215747", "3199427", "3200763", "10508668", 
"3129368", "3364621", "3129530", "3364620", "3351890", "3353248", 
"3354465", "3364533", "10508668"), closest_tss = c("5890748", 
"5890748", "13543366", "241569", "246793", "4113249", "4115603", 
"5316198", "5316198", "16656105", "16656105", "182094", "182094", 
"15235371", "14265809", "17268257", "17275733", "19374177", "1338846", 
"1338846", "1350520", "25255152", "25255152", "6151669", "6151669", 
"25000165", "25000165", "11715800", "11717935", "890797", "20521391", 
"11261367", "11263819", "17658257", "17658257", "14057026", "14057026", 
"283822", "286867", "532330", "25234249", "25234249", "820047", 
"9898149", "11840957", "11859315", "12531848", "19939783", "14006195", 
"14008382", "27563568", "31886482", "32060916", "32060916", "32064069", 
"32069099", "31070957", "31061675", "19340176", "19340176", "19829824", 
"19829824", "8811982", "8814998", "18795008", "20259649", "28657633", 
"31055196", "9018299", "9018299", "3057807", "3298832", "3059832", 
"3145971", "3059832", "3299872", "3145971", "3298832", "2789862", 
"2789862", "3135320", "3139161", "3189141", "3273809", "3135320", 
"3140087", "2796374", "3312731", "3060699", "3178357", "3057807", 
"3277562", "8257650", "8370577", "3145248", "3148645", "4574256", 
"4574256", "3098935", "3126252", "3126252", "3126252", "3126252", 
"3135320", "17286244", "17310250", "17286244", "17295221", "17286244", 
"17310250", "17293776", "17295221", "17295221", "17310250", "3160195", 
"3207012", "3136548", "1129313", "1131770", "1131036", "1131770", 
"12467784", "12577648", "13954948", "13983709", "3671809", "3673650", 
"2987588", "3114336", "3086586", "3175247", "3158830", "3266145", 
"2796374", "3211949", "8854450", "8854730", "3001932", "3162150", 
"3120568", "3193681", "3193681", "5451520", "3033223", "3135356", 
"3157139", "3158830", "3158830", "3390286", "3392454", "3394065", 
"3005037", "3322419", "3005037", "3237506", "3005037", "3322419", 
"17074858", "17131117", "2979368", "3192314", "5216362", "5216362", 
"3139206", "3201897", "3161839", "3162150", "3135320", "3140087", 
"3084631", "3144865", "3135320", "3140071", "3138191", "3197450", 
"3067779", "3160195", "19891412", "19893040", "3170458", "3193681", 
"3197450", "3197456", "3162150", "3162150", "2794208", "3266145", 
"4586282", "4589283", "3170458", "3197456", "3197456", "3215766", 
"3197456", "3201897", "10507151", "3128923", "3364643", "3128923", 
"3364643", "3351876", "3353858", "3355013", "3364523", "10507151"
), min_dist = c(-543, -28, -2787, 2383, -1866, -36, 2608, 1863, 
1986, -783, -653, -3883, -181, -950, -196, 211, -241, -1341, 
-4852, 4740, -4570, -1971, -1739, 1524, 1920, -1071, 131, 782, 
-862, 135, 937, -32, -221, -2266, -1673, 2191, 2336, 416, -777, 
405, -2544, -2300, -2905, -3260, -119, 2285, 2329, 1342, 84, 
-128, 43, 255, -8, 280, 2137, -707, 2858, 1527, 37, 189, -907, 
17, 344, 427, -563, 1537, -345, 2218, -4068, -4068, 128, 491, 
-434, -37, -434, -118, -37, 492, 1684, 1887, -1, -65, -89, 37, 
-1058, 697, 415, -442, 153, -765, -236, -173, -689, -1253, 221, 
-601, 56, 2352, -617, -552, -558, 724, 724, -281, -193, 1222, 
-192, -593, -192, 1222, -580, -594, -593, 1222, -15, 176, 194, 
394, -290, -565, -290, -624, -386, 33, 215, -300, -209, 777, 
-80, 196, 314, 225, 70, 799, 438, 82, -94, 274, 21, 150, 999, 
999, -67, 268, -17, -12, 46, 230, -264, -14, -302, 955, -164, 
957, 1604, 957, -162, -509, 1248, 3135, 289, 2129, 2761, 312, 
-1746, -173, 3064, -1046, 31, 231, -1094, -25, -304, 315, -906, 
-625, -484, -654, -628, 224, 700, -1805, 2213, 486, 3346, -955, 
24, 111, -583, -722, 1969, 1969, -19, 1971, -1134, 1517, 445, 
-22, 607, -23, 14, -610, -548, 10, 1517)), row.names = c(NA, 
-205L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("bp", 
"closest_tss", "min_dist"))
```

**Simulated**

```
structure(list(bp = c("15841782", "19207567", "12265239", "18258578", 
"17474424", "13497502", "8941922", "7206477", "2960535", "15815282", 
"13554212", "3945784", "12251319", "5105476", "1373949", "17954973", 
"20559910", "11667512", "16611027", "14046021", "20214248", "15157830", 
"1422239", "21893567", "2131253", "16603989", "13145764", "17020364", 
"15402269", "15550900", "19233567", "12489308", "10214593", "20200305", 
"15255298", "7709179", "9717823", "16438675", "911096", "5397453", 
"12669870", "9971572", "12137058", "22519767", "9086005", "2073768", 
"19105685", "4660151", "3194908", "1074861", "18771285", "24633527", 
"29193721", "18717352", "27022089", "30859960", "4736659", "8793673", 
"15507442", "29032674", "11513084", "26683562", "10813081", "10307320", 
"18288437", "16204754", "30450304", "1517564", "7450046", "4265942", 
"21540549", "30909022", "29899213", "10727663", "12289103", "3541635", 
"7450798", "12980760", "4775560", "19391908", "11854119", "15226678", 
"7830014", "11022110", "20666948", "6675438", "16668968", "16274842", 
"21587666", "15739447", "16509180", "3465258", "20448537", "20910321", 
"9291611", "14354738", "17004086", "10970286", "20665363", "14714913", 
"10148837", "15199311", "9517898", "19282236", "1894548", "17723231", 
"13777750", "4317306", "19969615", "5147426", "23068409", "7351103", 
"16468899", "5014553", "13917402", "312171", "8142742", "2447437", 
"16989629", "18426580", "5002193", "3045967", "151988", "4915511", 
"21190974", "477407", "8339511", "3640008", "19329507", "4644328", 
"20135064", "20993674", "10047595", "10090678", "14679875", "3638225", 
"4768816", "9986109", "10289915", "20240058", "18741182", "6695445", 
"5276276", "4517868", "16915182", "2543803", "1245702", "19907046", 
"17305293", "6949581", "8857904", "10952922", "2759740", "11518155", 
"6185820", "8424726", "8012040", "10564171", "12273415", "18529404", 
"2200536", "8679714", "17975100", "3840654", "19327125", "11915622", 
"11883702", "22443887", "2969175", "4757711", "12734286", "18112160", 
"3844437", "357789", "1558999", "9535397", "17590187", "2552927", 
"10371547", "13762640", "5935940", "3490059", "3949054", "20809373", 
"12922705", "9541347", "16964313", "15430603", "15892706", "16740024", 
"17049353", "2043325", "8727914", "14930107", "14596403", "9137411", 
"21158311", "741790", "13062353", "22936151"), closest_tss = c("15844362", 
"19204850", "12265269", "18258710", "17475486", "13498238", "8940796", 
"7207410", "2961489", "15814544", "13554892", "3945626", "12251415", 
"5105195", "1373846", "17957388", "20562941", "11667697", "16612171", 
"14045663", "20214701", "15152867", "1422182", "21893852", "2129140", 
"16604003", "13145476", "17020838", "15401753", "15551389", "19234162", 
"12487791", "10213980", "20200561", "15258773", "7709283", "9715706", 
"16438869", "913064", "5398043", "12670364", "9969597", "12136220", 
"22523062", "9083882", "2074022", "19103184", "4660484", "3194381", 
"1074468", "18771409", "24634502", "29194581", "18718845", "27023353", 
"30859633", "4737023", "8793068", "15506198", "29037254", "11513235", 
"26683311", "10813727", "10312157", "18288741", "16207440", "30451147", 
"1515291", "7449225", "4265246", "21540644", "30910516", "29899078", 
"10727943", "12289648", "3541963", "7448291", "12979305", "4775955", 
"19392318", "11857401", "15224836", "7830579", "11022575", "20667555", 
"6678430", "16671653", "16277599", "21583805", "15741616", "16508862", 
"3468355", "20449432", "20910647", "9290674", "14354856", "17006642", 
"10972622", "20663687", "14714861", "10149855", "15201203", "9519023", 
"19282482", "1891493", "17723571", "13777347", "4313083", "19969656", 
"5147484", "23066571", "7351171", "16469034", "5014617", "13918503", 
"312937", "8143558", "2448887", "16988511", "18426200", "5001796", 
"3047606", "152030", "4915040", "21191808", "477488", "8341240", 
"3639230", "19329361", "4645326", "20133788", "20992435", "10046217", 
"10090666", "14681918", "3637970", "4768818", "9986006", "10290005", 
"20244412", "18745661", "6695930", "5276765", "4517906", "16914839", 
"2542731", "1245688", "19907278", "17304520", "6949661", "8857732", 
"10953286", "2761533", "11516650", "6185241", "8426425", "8012901", 
"10566684", "12273323", "18529947", "2196393", "8680374", "17973753", 
"3841311", "19327314", "11916835", "11885116", "22447631", "2971185", 
"4758227", "12734418", "18110983", "3844046", "354786", "1555639", 
"9536049", "17592041", "2553902", "10370683", "13763011", "5936315", 
"3490342", "3948851", "20808940", "12921727", "9541150", "16967855", 
"15432932", "15893445", "16739902", "17053195", "2040815", "8729070", 
"14929727", "14596487", "9136883", "21161257", "739839", "13062761", 
"22934375"), min_dist = c(-2580, 2717, -30, -132, -1062, -736, 
1126, -933, -954, 738, -680, 158, -96, 281, 103, -2415, -3031, 
-185, -1144, 358, -453, 4963, 57, -285, 2113, -14, 288, -474, 
516, -489, -595, 1517, 613, -256, -3475, -104, 2117, -194, -1968, 
-590, -494, 1975, 838, -3295, 2123, -254, 2501, -333, 527, 393, 
-124, -975, -860, -1493, -1264, 327, -364, 605, 1244, -4580, 
-151, 251, -646, -4837, -304, -2686, -843, 2273, 821, 696, -95, 
-1494, 135, -280, -545, -328, 2507, 1455, -395, -410, -3282, 
1842, -565, -465, -607, -2992, -2685, -2757, 3861, -2169, 318, 
-3097, -895, -326, 937, -118, -2556, -2336, 1676, 52, -1018, 
-1892, -1125, -246, 3055, -340, 403, 4223, -41, -58, 1838, -68, 
-135, -64, -1101, -766, -816, -1450, 1118, 380, 397, -1639, -42, 
471, -834, -81, -1729, 778, 146, -998, 1276, 1239, 1378, 12, 
-2043, 255, -2, 103, -90, -4354, -4479, -485, -489, -38, 343, 
1072, 14, -232, 773, -80, 172, -364, -1793, 1505, 579, -1699, 
-861, -2513, 92, -543, 4143, -660, 1347, -657, -189, -1213, -1414, 
-3744, -2010, -516, -132, 1177, 391, 3003, 3360, -652, -1854, 
-975, 864, -371, -375, -283, 203, 433, 978, 197, -3542, -2329, 
-739, 122, -3842, 2510, -1156, 380, -84, 528, -2946, 1951, -408, 
1776)), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .Names = c("bp", "closest_tss", "min_dist"))
```

Comment: Kurtosis is a matter of shape, not spread (disperson, scale). So, clustering around the midpoint could be absolute (spread) and/or relative (kurtosis). Evidently your kurtosis is on a scale on which  normal is 0. People have been arguing for decades on what kurtosis measures (apart from kurtosis): an intricate and often fraught  debate aside, the best verbal summary I can offer is tail weight.  I'd plot distributions as a quantile-quantile plot here. Density estimates can be a little too sensitive to kernel width  The marginal rugs give  flavour rather than insight. Can you post the data? .

Comment: @NickCox - Thanks - I've added data to the question

Comment: "I am really interested in knowing whether the empirical data "clusters" around the midpoint of the plot 0 more than the simulated data" tells us your are not interested in kurtosis, but in some measure of *spread.*  Kurtosis is not such a measure.  Standard deviation, MAD, and IQR are examples of measures of spread.

Comment: Just a clarification: The comment "kurtosis reflects the sharpness of the distribution" is simply wrong. The beta(1,.5) distribution is infinitely "sharp" and has negative excess kurtosis. The .9999*U(0.1) + .0001*N(0,100000) distribution is flat ("not sharp") but has huge kurtosis.  Kurtosis measures tails of the distribution only, and nothing about the peak.

Answer (score 6):

*This answer is oblique to your question, because I am not clear that it's the best question to ask. Whether kurtosis is higher or lower doesn't bear directly on the main differences in level, spread and shape between empirical and simulated distributions.*

I can't comment on what is of most scientific interest here. I don't doubt that conventional tests for differences in mean and/or variance will show something: for example, $t$ tests comparing means give $P$-values of around 0.04. But either seems to miss a major point, which is a difference in distribution shape.

Here are overlaid quantile plots, first with reference distribution uniform and second with reference distribution normal (Gaussian).

What I see most prominently is that empirical and simulated distributions differ most in the left-hand tails. That is consistent with the density plots, but conversely the rather pronounced bump in the right tail of the latter looks a little like over-reaction to a small cluster of values (compare the rug).

[image]

[image]

A strong merit of quantile plots here is that there are no arbitrary or capricious choices of how and how much to smooth (let alone how, and how much, to bin, where binning not only ignores detail within bins but also is sensitive to bin start and width). The data are plotted as they come, signal, fine structure and noise all together. A limitation of Kolmogorov-Smirnov and similar tests is that you still need to look to see where any differences occur. I'd rather start with looking at the data further.

Answer (score 2):

**At issue is what you mean by "clusters ... around 0."**  In practice you might not know for sure.  Therefore, this answer proposes a flexible exploratory determination: namely, the degree of clustering around any point ought to depend on the scale at which you are viewing the clustering, so for insight, **study how apparent clustering depends on the scale.**

This suggests developing a quantitative measure of degree of clustering as a function of the scale.  Given the data have been presented in terms of kernel density estimates (KDEs), and given that the amount of data near a given value are proportional to the estimated density at that value, a natural choice is the value of a KDE at 0.  Any KDE depends on a scale factor, typically represented as a kernel half-width.  Specifically, for a kernel function $k$ and scale factor $h,$ the KDE of a dataset $x=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ at $0$ is

$$\rho(h;x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n hk\left(\frac{0-x_i}{h}\right)= \frac{h}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n k\left(-\frac{x_i}{h}\right).$$

This "peak density trace" is a fast, efficient calculation.  You can therefore compare two datasets $x$ and $y=(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m)$ at *all* scales by plotting the graphs of  $h\to \rho(h;x)$ and $h\to \rho(h;y)$ on the same axes, as shown by this figure for the data in the question:

[image: Figure]

*The plots for $x$ (the empirical data) are shown in yellow and those for $y$ (the simulated data) in blue.  At left are the graphs of $\rho$ on log-log axes (using a Gaussian kernel).  At right are the two densities for a particular half-width (the one located by the vertical line in the left plot).*

**In this case there is no question about the clustering:** no matter what the scale is (over a wide range) the empirical data look more clustered at $0,$ because at each horizontal coordinate in the left-hand plot the yellow ($x$) graph is higher than the blue ($y$) graph.

**To appreciate what this approach can offer,** consider a circumstance where the answer does depend on the scale.  I simulated mixtures of two Normal variables, both centered at zero.  The $x$ data use standard deviations of $1$ and $1/2$ while the $y$ data use standard deviations of $5$ and $1/8.$  These mixture components represent clustering around zero at four different scales, with $y$ using the two most extreme scales.  We should therefore expect the determination of "more clustered" to depend on scale, and indeed it does, as reflected by the next figure.

[image: Figure 2]

The traces of peak density at the left now cross: at half widths of $1/2$ or less, the blue ($y$) curve is higher, indicating greater clustering by $y;$ at larger half-widths, the yellow ($x$) curve is higher, indicating greater clustering by $x.$  Kernel density estimates for three half-widths (as shown by the vertical lines in the left plot) illustrate this variable clustering.

> To describe and compare the clustering around 0 you may use the peak density trace to either select an appropriate scale (and choose the dataset with greatest density at 0 as the most clustered) or stop with the trace itself, letting it reveal how clustering varies with scale.

**Finally, if you are concerned the result might depend on the choice of the kernel,** know that it is unlikely to do so, but you can perform a sensitivity analysis by choosing some extreme kernels (such as a uniform and a bi-exponential) and viewing the density traces for them to see how much they might have changed.  As an example, here is a re-analysis for the data in the question carried out for a uniform ("rectangular") kernel:

[image: Figure 3]

Qualitatively it is the same as before and leads to the same conclusion about clustering: **at all scales, $x$ is more clustered around $0$ than $y.$**

---

#### Appendix: `R` code to create the figures

```R
#
# Generate random data.
# Alternatively: let `x` and `y` be real datasets, as in the question.
#
# set.seed(17)
# x <- c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, sd=0.5))
# y <- c(rnorm(100, sd=5), rnorm(100, sd=0.125))
#
# Figure out a reasonable range of kernel half-widths `h`.
#
s <- diff(range(c(x,y)))
n <- min(length(x), length(y))
d <- 2*s / (length(x) + length(y))
h <- exp(seq(log(d), log(s), length.out=101))
#
# Compute the peak traces.
# `kstring` is an argument to `density`.
#
rho <- function(h, x) mean(dnorm(-x, 0, h)) # Gaussian kernel
kstring <- "gaussian"
# rho <- function(h, x) mean(dunif(-x, -h*sqrt(3), h*sqrt(3))) # Rectangular kernel
# kstring <- "rectangular"
x.plot <- sapply(h, rho, x=x)
y.plot <- sapply(h, rho, x=y)
#
# Create consistent plotting colors.
#
col.make <- function(col, h, s, v, a) {
  q <- do.call("rgb2hsv", as.list(col2rgb(col)))
  if (!missing(h)) q[1] <- h
  if (!missing(s)) q[2] <- s
  if (!missing(v)) q[3] <- v
  hsv(q[1], q[2], q[3], a)
}
x.col <- col.make("#F4E5AE", s=0.8); x.cola <- col.make(x.col, a=0.25)
y.col <- col.make("#B1E0E4", s=0.8); y.cola <- col.make(y.col, a=0.25)
#
# Quick and dirty: obtain the half-width estimated by `density` for reference.
#
x.kde <- density(x, kernel=kstring)
y.kde <- density(y, kernel=kstring)
bw <- signif(max(x.kde$bw, y.kde$bw), 1)
#
# Make the plots.
#
# mult <- c(1,2.5,10) # Multipliers of `bw` to display
mult <- 1
par(mfrow=c(1, length(mult)+1))

#-- The peak trace plots
plot(h, pmax(y.plot, x.plot), log="xy", type="n", 
     main="Densities at 0",
     xlab="Kernel half width", ylab="Peak density")
abline(v = bw*mult)
lines(h, x.plot, lwd=2, col=x.col)
lines(h, y.plot, lwd=2, col=y.col)

#-- The density plot(s)
for (bw in bw * mult) {
  x.kde <- density(x, bw=bw, kernel=kstring)
  y.kde <- density(y, bw=bw, kernel=kstring)
  plot(range(c(x.kde$x, y.kde$x)), range(c(x.kde$y, y.kde$y)), type="n",
       xlab="Value", ylab="Density",  
       main=paste0("Kernel Densities at Half-width ", bw))
  abline(v = 0)
  polygon(x.kde$x, x.kde$y, border=NA, col=x.cola)
  lines(x.kde, lwd=2, col=x.col)
  polygon(y.kde$x, y.kde$y, border=NA, col=y.cola)
  lines(y.kde, lwd=2, col=y.col)
}

par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: nice analysis. would be there source code fo all this available? many thanks.

Comment: @Maximilian I have appended the code to the post because it's too long for a comment.  Note, though, that computing the two "peak trace" curves takes just three simple lines.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're looking for is a Levene's test of homogeneity of variance. It should test whether the variance in one distribution is significantly different from the variance in another distribution. Which should get at your question about how the data clusters.

This will not inform whether it is centered on 0 though. For that I would use a t-test. Between the combination of those two you should be able to answer your question.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levene%27s_test

Answer (score 0):

The OP states,

"I am interested in whether my empirical data (yellow) "clusters" around the midpoint of the plot more than the simulated data (blue)."

This is not a question about kurtosis: kurtosis does not measure "clustering" around the midpoint. Rather, it measures tails of the distribution. (Rare, extreme potentially observable data).

Here is a visual image to help understand the above comment.  Compute the z-values for each sample. Plot the $z^4$ values for the observed data sample using a dot plot.

Now, compute the average of the $z^4$ values for the simulated data; this is the kurtosis of the simulated data.

Now, locate the kurtosis of the simulated data as a "fulcrum" on the horizontal axis of your dot plot of your observed data $z^4$ values. If the dot plot "falls to the right," then your observed data have higher kurtosis than the simulated data, and conversely.

Now, what causes the "falling to the right"? Is it greater "clustering around the midpoint" of your actual data?  Obviously, not, because it falls to the right, not to the left. So, higher kurtosis implies greater tail weight (rare, extreme value(s)), not greater "clustering around a midpoint."

If you want to compare "clustering around the midpoint," you might instead consider comparing the difference between 10th and 90th percentiles (or other similar). You could use a bootstrap-type (perhaps smoothed) method to estimate standard error of the difference.